# Intersection of 3d layers in PostGIS with SQL Queries

Tags: postgis, sql, query, intersect

I am currently working on a project for Uni with PostGIS and SQL Queries. I am trying to calculate the intersection between two 3d layers.
Based on online tutorials I came up with this query.

```
SELECT ST_3DIntersects(geom1,geom2);
FROM (St_astext (ST_extrude(geom,0,0,50)) floodpd as geom1,
      (surface_geometry as geom2)) As t;
```

But it does not seem to work.
How would I be able to calculate the intersection?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Do you get any error messages or what do you mean by not working?